# bokeh server host whitelist appending

Tags: python, bokeh

I'm new to Bokeh and I'm trying to run a server. I ran the command:

```
[uid@localhost bokeh_apps]$ bokeh serve --show myapp --port 5100 --host 127.0.0.1:80
```

A Window popped out and I had to quit the "Elinks", and the output kept going:

```
INFO:bokeh.server.tornado:Rejected connection from host 'localhost:5100' because it is not in the --host whitelist
WARNING:tornado.access:403 GET /myapp (::1) 1.71ms
DEBUG:bokeh.server.tornado:[pid 834] 0 clients connected
```

I googled and all I can find is a [GitHub issue page](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/4051). I read it but don't understand whether there's a solution in the [tornado.py](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/bokeh/server/tornado.py#L29-L42).

Are there some args/parameters that can solve this? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

If you are just running things locally, you don't need the `--host 127.0.0.1:80`, in fact that is the source of your problem. By default, `localhost:<PORT>` in the whitelist, *unless* you explicitly provide a `--host` option as you have done. The `--host` option is typically only needed when deploying e.g. behind a reverse proxy, and you want to protect against requests with spoofed hostnames.